# A part of the power has gone off

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

More than half of the appliances are working. But a few are not working because (it's not like half the power is out, actually more than half the power is on and just a part of it is out, maybe because of a problem in the circuit):

> A part of the power has gone off.

Is the use of "a part of" natural?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unnatural, as one can’t have a ‘part of the power’; on the other hand, one could say ‘there’s a partial power outage’.
I’d describe this by saying ‘the power’s partially out’.

Comment: And what about: Half the power's out?

Comment: This would likely be considered natural in spoken English, but probably not in written English.

Comment: What can be used in "formal English ?